# git rev-parse HEAD returned non-zero exit status 128

Tags: git, gitlab

Facing this issue for git commit:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
....
 File "C:\Repo\xyz\extern\VerFw\Src\ComponentLineImporter\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .Version import __version__
  File "C:\Repo\xyz\extern\VerFw\Src\ComponentLineImporter\Version.py", line 22, in <module>
    __version__ = subprocess.check_output('git rev-parse HEAD', cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))).decode().strip()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git rev-parse HEAD' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

Why I get this error when there is no such duplicate folder of `ComponentLineImporter` in my only repo?

Comment: No such duplicate folder... what now? I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, and show the Python code? We don't have much to work with here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to CD (change directory) to your git repository. You are either not in the correct path or you didn't create a git repository yet using `create`.

Make you your terminal is located under an existing git repository. using `bash` for instance you should see the name of your branch too.

for instance:

```
MINGW64 ~/../Source_code/pylint_Forked (master)
$
```